# Can I use a Triban RC120 with a TacX direct drive smart trainer?

Tags: cassette, turbo-trainer, indoor

I have a Triban RC 120 road bike from Decathlon ([link](https://www.decathlon.in/p/8544693/heavy-products/triban-rc-120-cycle-touring-road-bike)). It runs a Microshift 2x8 speed system.

I plan on getting a direct drive smart trainer from TacX ([TacX Flux](https://www.garmin.co.in/products/intosports/tacx-flux-s-smart-trainer/)). I wanted to know if I can use this road bike with this trainer? I am concerned if the two will work properly and shift etc. properly when used with Rouvy or Zwift.

I have tried to google this and not gotten anywhere. I also tried reaching out to local bike shops and Decathlon and they dont seem to have a clue either.

Comment: An interesting combination, the trainer will be much more expensive than the bike. Most would choose to buy a better bike instead.

Comment: Buying a better bike would no doubt mean no trainer. OP could always use n+1 logic and get a better bike and trainer.

Comment: you are both correct. i could buy a better bike and also the trainer but there are other competing uses for a limited sum of money. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work:

- the freebody is the almost the same as the R8: the trainer has the longer version of the Shimano Hyperglide free body (to allow 11 speeds road cassettes). You will need a spacer to fit a 8-speed cassette, that should be provided in the package of the Flux.
- I don't know if the RC120 uses a 130mm or 135mm rear fork width, but the Flux is compatible with the two widths anyway.
- The RC120 uses a quick release system, that is supported by the Flux.

Comment: Microshift cassettes are compatible with SRAM and Shimano hubs.

Comment: thank you for your response @Renaud. Any videos etc. you could point me to for more info on this spacer and hub?

Comment: Everything is explained in the user manual (you can find a link to the PDF from the product page that you gave).

Comment: @Renaud thanks for your help. I got the trainer and mounted the bike. Everything is working as it should. Thanks.!